# VueJS how to toggle subitems from an active item

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have some items which unfold some subtitems when you click on each item. Right now, when you click on each item, the subitems gets unfolded, so that they lap over each other so, what I'm trying to achieve is, that when you click an item, the subitems unfold and when you click another item, the previous subitems close and the subitems which belong to the clicked item unfolds.

So I have this:

Component 1:

```
<Card 
   v-for="item in content.items"
   :key="item.id"
   :content="item"
/>
```

Component 2:

```
<div>
   <Item @click="onClick" :title="some title"/>
 </div>
 <div v-if="content.items" ref="items">
    <Subitem
        v-for="child in content.items"
        :key="child.id"
        :content="child"
    />
</div>

export default {
   data: () => ({
      isOpen: false,
   }),
   methods: {
    onClick(e) {
        if (
            this.content.items &&
            this.content.items.length &&
            this.$refs.items
        ) {
            e.preventDefault();

            this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;

            gsap.to(this.$refs.items, {
                height: this.isOpen ? '100%' : 0,
                duration: this.isOpen ? 0.2 : 0.2,
                delay: this.isOpen ? 0 : 0.044,
            });
        }
   }
}
```

So this opens the subitems when I click on one of the items - but when I click another item, it doesn't close the active items subitems and instead lays over it the other subitems.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into emitting custom events. Here is the documentation you need : [VueJS documentation for custom events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html)

You could also look into VueX